# Dynamically add class variables to classes inheriting mixin class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a mixin class, that adds some functionality to inheriting classes, but the mixin requires some class attributes to be present, for simplicity let's say only one property `handlers`. So this would be the usage of the mixin:

```
class Mixin:
    pass

class Something(Mixin):
    handlers = {}
```

The mixin can't function without this being defined, but I really don't want to specify the `handlers` in every class that I want to use the mixin with. So I solved this by writing a metaclass:

```
class MixinMeta:
    def __new__(mcs, *args, **kwargs):
        cls = super().__new__(mcs, *args, **kwargs)
        cls.handlers = {}
        return cls

class Mixin(metaclass=MixinMeta):
    pass
```

And this works exactly how I want it to. But I'm thinking this can become a huge problem, since metaclasses don't work well together (I read various metaclass conflicts can only be solved by creating a new metaclass that resolves those conflicts).

Also, I don't want to make the `handlers` property a property of the `Mixin` class itself, since that would mean having to store handlers by their class names inside the `Mixin` class, complicating the code a bit. I like having each class having their handlers on their own class - it makes working with them simpler, but clearly this has drawbacks.

My question is, what would be a better way to implement this? I'm fairly new to metaclasses, but they seem to solve this problem well. But metaclass conflicts are clearly a huge issue when dealing with complex hierarchies without having to define various metaclasses just to resolve those conflicts.

Comment: *"this can become a huge problem"* - and what if it doesn't?

Comment: Python 3.6 is going to get an [`__init_subclass__`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487/) hook that'll let you do what you want without metaclasses, but 3.6 isn't here yet.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well it does in the most trivial case. I have one metaclass with which all widgets are constructed. Now that metaclass is extended a couple of times, each with their separate use case. Now suppose I want to make a widget that use those metaclasses and my metaclass, I would need to make as many metaclasses to just handle the conflicts as there are those other classes for one single additional metaclass. This does not seem viable to me.

Comment: @user2357112 Unfortunately, I am using Python 3.4, so that won't be an option for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is very real, and Python folks have thought of this for Python 3.6 (still unrealsed) on. For now (up to Python 3.5), if your attributes can wait to exist until your classes are first instantiated, you could put cod to create a (class) attribute on the `__new__` method of your mixin class itself - thus avoiding the (extra) metaclass:

```
class Mixin:
    def __new__(cls):
         if not hasattr(cls, handlers):
              cls.handlers = {}
         return super().__new__(cls)
```

For Python 3.6 on, [PEP 487](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487/) defines a `__init_subclass__` special method to go on the mixin class body. This special method is not called for the mixin class itself, but will be called at the end of `type.__new__` method (the "root" metaclass) for each class that inherits from your mixin.

```
class Mixin:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
         cls.handlers = {}
         return super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
```

As per the PEP's background text, the main motivation for this is exactly what led you to ask your question: avoid the need for meta-classes when simple customization of class creation is needed, in order to reduce the chances of needing different metaclasses in a project, and thus triggering a situation of metaclass conflict.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll definitely try out the `__new__` solution!

Comment: I appreciate the help, unfortunately your solution didn't work since I had to access those properties before any class was instantiated. I ended up solving the problem by creating a descriptor to create a central registry of handlers on the base Mixin class. Not ideal, but it works. Regardless, thank you very much!